# Youtube video webview is overlapping on the other layout in android

Tags: java, android

I have a webview in my application and its working fine, but when there is a youtube video embeded in that url then the webview is overlapping on the other layout and that layout get covered. As far as I did here is the code:

```
web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);



web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
web.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
web.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

web.loadUrl("http://savebigshopper.com/amazon");
```

here is the image where I can show how the layout gets displaced:

[image]

Comment: Grab a screenshot for everyone to see if you can.